# Using git to copy files

Tags: git, file, copy

How can I use git to copy the files I changed in a pimarily worked in (./bll) to another directory (./bll_remote), which actually is a softlink to another directory (which is in a mounted webdav-directory, that's the background) with `git push`?

btw I am quite new to git, so I may not have understood everything regarding the concept of repositories (so probably that's why the solutions i found at google did not work properly for me)!

Edit: I forgot to mention, one solution seemed to work — `git remote add ../bll_remote` followed by `git push -u origin master` returned it would have finished writing 3.2MiB — but when i looked into that dir, it only showed up these strange files created due to the `--bare` option, but nowhere in there were the added and pushed files… what did I do wrong?
Or, different question, why have I to use the `--bare` option to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "bare" repository does not contain a working directory. The "strainge files" you see are all the data that git uses to recreate the files under version control. If you want a full repository, you should probably start over and reinitialize the target directory without the `--bare` option.

Comment: but when I execute `git init` on `bll_remote/` and then execute `git init; git add *; git commit -m "Files added"; git remote add origin ../bll_remote; git push -u origin master` on `bll/` it returns
“remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/head/master
By yefault, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository is denied […]”

Comment: Seems to get quite difficult… isn't there a simpler way to just copy a dir in git??

Comment: @LukasJuhrich Google that error and you will find the necessary changes to your config file to get around it.